# Why can't I initialize an array in my init.d script?

Tags: bash, init.d

First line of script --

```
PATHS=()
```

results in `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

What is going on here?  Can I not use arrays in my init.d script?  Is it being interpreted by a shell that uses different syntax for arrays?

Running on Ubuntu 10.04 server.

Comment: Because this is running in `/bin/sh` not `bin/bash`

Comment: You can check the shell with `readlink -f /bin/sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it isn't a bash script (despite the fact that somebody had made the shebang line #!bin/bash).  Ubuntu uses [dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell), which requires different syntax.